# Javascript - Vars, Functions and Objects

Tags: javascript, function, object, var

I'm coming from AS3 to HTML5 javascript so this is kinda confusing:

1.

I noticed that inside objects, you do not need to declare vars:

```
var player = { 
type:'player',
x:50,
}
```

The same thing with vars (var type, var x) display errors, why is that?

2 . Why don't I need to declare a var in a function:

```
createPlayer = function(){
a = 5;
console.log(a); //works
}
```

3.
 I assume that inside a function, once you create a new var like this:

```
 var a; //global var
 createPlayer = function(){
 a = 3;
 }
```

it first searches to see if there's a global var called a, if it already exists it changes it's value, if not it creates it locally in the function. is that correct?

4. Generally, when do I need to declare a var, and when not?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: Just NEVER assigned a variable without declaring it first using `var` and then you will never be confused about what scope it is defined in.  if you don't declare a variable with `var`, it becomes a global variable and this is considered a very bad practice and, in fact, will actually be an error in strict mode.

Comment: Duplicate? [What is the function of the var keyword and when to use it (or omit it)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1470488/218196)

Answer (score 4):

1. Because variables and properties are different things.

   When you declare variable, use `var`. When you set properties in an object literal, don't.
2. You don't have to use `var` in non-strict mode, but it's not recommended because the variable will become global. And not using `var` throws in strict mode.
3. When you set some value to a variable, it's searched in the scope chain, and modified there. If the variable is not found anywhere, it's an error in strict-mode, or assigned as a property of the global object in non-strict mode.
4. **Always** declare your variables somewhere. And preferably, as locally as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the keyword `var` inside a function then it is considered as a **local variable** otherwise it is considered as a **global variable** attached to the window object, let me give you this example

```
function test(){
    var attr1 = "first attribute"; // this is a local variable 
    attr2 = "second attribute"; // this is a global variable, so you can acess it from outside that function, once you call it  
}

// call the test function 
test();
console.log(attr1); // we get undefined because we used the keyword var
console.log(attr2); // we  get the valeu "second attribute" because it is considered as a global variable
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, it did help.

Comment: Thumbs up if it helps :)